# Why does thmtools not apply multiple theorem filters in \listoftheorems?

Tags: lists, theorems, thmtools

I'm looking to create a theorem and definition list with `thmtools`'s `\listoftheorems` for my thesis.

I have the following theorem types (grouped by style)

- *Lemma*, *Proposition*, *Corollary*, *Theorem*
- *Definition*, *Algorithm*, *Notation*
- *Example*, *Note*

and associated theorem declarations.

When I tell `\listoftheorems` to only show the first group (by `\listoftheorems[ignoreall, show={lemmathm, propositionthm, corollarythm, theoremthm}]` (where `lemmathm`, etc. are the environment names), the list also includes entries for the other two groups.

The list of definitions created by `\listoftheorems[ignoreall, show={definitionthm}]` is correct however.

My command invocation doesn't seem to be wrong. I adapted it from the example in the `thmtools` documentation

Is there a known problem with multiple filters (this is what it seems like)? Can someone provide a fix or work-around?

---

## MWE

The following MWE reproduces the error on my system. I have stripped dependencies with potential bad interaction as far as I could. — Please excuse the German. ;)

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, openany, hidelinks]{book}

%!%!%!%!%!%!
% packages %
%!%!%!%!%!%!

%
% decoding/ encoding
% 
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

%
% fonts & symbols
%
\usepackage{bera}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}


%
% layout
%
\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}
\usepackage{listings}

%!%!%!%!%!%!
% commands %
%!%!%!%!%!%!

%
% font commands
%
\newcommand{\berafamily}{\fontfamily{fve}\selectfont}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% theorem commands %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%
% Sub theorem counters.
%
\newcounter{subtheoremcounter}
\setcounter{subtheoremcounter}{0}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    spaceabove=1em, 
    spacebelow=1em, 
    headfont=\normalsize\bfseries\berafamily, 
    bodyfont=\rmfamily\normalsize,
    postheadspace=\parindent, 
    postheadhook={\hfill\newline\setcounter{subtheoremcounter}{0}},
    qed=$\square$, 
    headpunct={.}]{proof-style} 

\declaretheorem[numberwithin=chapter, style=proof-style, name=Theorem]{theoremthm}
\declaretheorem[numberlike=theoremthm, style=proof-style, name=Proposition]{propositionthm}
\declaretheorem[numberlike=theoremthm, style=proof-style, name=Lemma]{lemmathm}
\declaretheorem[numberlike=theoremthm, style=proof-style, name=Korollar]{corollarythm}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    spaceabove=1em, 
    spacebelow=1em, 
    headfont=\normalsize\bfseries\berafamily, 
    bodyfont=\rmfamily\normalsize,
    postheadspace=\parindent, 
    postheadhook={%
        \hfill\newline%
        \setcounter{subtheoremcounter}{0}},
    qed=$\blacksquare$, 
    headpunct={.}]{definition-style} 

\declaretheorem[numberlike=theoremthm, style=definition-style, name=Definition]{definitionthm}
\declaretheorem[numberlike=theoremthm, style=definition-style, name=Algorithm]{algorithmthm}
\declaretheorem[numberlike=theoremthm, style=definition-style, name=Notation]{notationthm}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    spaceabove=1em, 
    spacebelow=1em, 
    headfont=\normalsize\bfseries\berafamily, 
    bodyfont=\rmfamily\normalsize,
    postheadspace=\parindent, 
    postheadhook={\setcounter{subtheoremcounter}{0}},
    qed=$\blacksquare$]{example-style}

\declaretheorem[numberlike=theoremthm, style=example-style, name=Beispiel]{examplethm}
\declaretheorem[numberlike=theoremthm, style=example-style, name=Bemerkung]{notethm}

\makeatletter

%
% Title, date, institute, etc.
%
\title{<Titel>}
\author{<Autor>}
\date{\today}

%!%!%!%!%!%!        
% document %
%!%!%!%!%!%!
\begin{document}
\raggedbottom
%
% I. Front Matter
%
\frontmatter
%
% I.1 Title Page
%
\maketitle

%
% I.1 Inhaltsverzeichnis
% 
\tableofcontents

%
% II. Main Matter
%
\mainmatter
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Hauptteil}

%
% II.1
%
\chapter{Das erste Kapitel!}
\section{Der erste Abschnitt!}

\begin{definitionthm}[Definition A]%
\ldots
\end{definitionthm}

\begin{lemmathm}[Lemma 1]%
\ldots
\end{lemmathm}

\begin{notationthm}[Notation]
\ldots
\end{notationthm}

\begin{propositionthm}[Proposition 2]%
\ldots
\end{propositionthm}

\begin{notethm}
\ldots
\end{notethm}

\begin{examplethm}
\ldots
\end{examplethm}

\begin{theoremthm}[Theorem 3]%
\ldots
\end{theoremthm}

\section{Der Zweite Abschnitt!}

\begin{definitionthm}[Definition B]%
\ldots
\end{definitionthm}

\begin{definitionthm}[Definition C]%
\ldots
\end{definitionthm}

\begin{lemmathm}[Lemma 4]%
\ldots
\end{lemmathm}

\begin{lemmathm}[Lemma 5]%
\ldots
\end{lemmathm}

\begin{propositionthm}[Proposition 6]%
\ldots
\end{propositionthm}

\chapter{Das Zweite Kapitel!}
\section{Der Erste Abschnitt!}

\begin{definitionthm}[Definition D]%
\ldots
\end{definitionthm}

\begin{notethm}
\ldots
\end{notethm}

\begin{lemmathm}[Lemma 7]%
\ldots
\end{lemmathm}

\begin{examplethm}
\ldots
\end{examplethm}

\begin{theoremthm}[Theorem 8]%
\ldots
\end{theoremthm}

\begin{examplethm}
\ldots
\end{examplethm}

\begin{notationthm}[Notation]
\ldots
\end{notationthm}

%
% III. Anhang
%
\newpage
\appendix

\chapter*{Anhang}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Anhang}

%
% IV. Verzeichnisse
%
\backmatter
%\chapter*{Verzeichnisse}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Verzeichnisse}
%
% IV.1 Theoreme
%
\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{Theoremverzeichnis}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Theoremverzeichnis}
\listoftheorems[showall, ignore={definitionthm, notationthm, notethm, examplethm}]
%
% IV.2 Definitionen
%
\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{Definitionsverzeichnis}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Definitionsverzeichnis}
\listoftheorems[ignoreall, show={definitionthm}]
%
% IV.3 Tabellen
%
%\section*{Tabellenverzeichnis}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Tabellenverzeichnis}
\listoftables
%
% IV.4 Abbildungen
%
%\section*{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\listoffigures

%
% IV.5 Listings
%

%
%!ref http://stackoverflow.com/a/9480618
%
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Listingverzeichnis}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Listingverzeichnis}
\lstlistoflistings


\end{document}
```

Comment: You should really get the habit of saving your files as UTF-8 rather than in MacRoman.

Comment: "You should really get the habit of saving your files as UTF-8 rather than in MacRoman. " Meaning what?

Comment: There's no need to save files in the MacRoman encoding, which limits portability. Maximum portability is obtained by using UTF-8. Are you using TeXShop?

Comment: @egreg Yeah I'm using TeXShop. I remember that using UTF-8 with german Umlaut accents didn't work on my mac. That's why I switched to applemac input encoding. I might be wrong, though. Haven't tried to change back to UTF-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid spaces in the options to `show`:

```
\listoftheorems[ignoreall, show={lemmathm,propositionthm,corollarythm,theoremthm}]
```

By the way, you should use `\cleardoublepage` before the `\addcontentsline` instructions.

[image]

Of course you should also act on the space reserved for the numbers, but this is another matter.

---

With your command

```
\listoftheorems[ignoreall, show={lemmathm, propositionthm, corollarythm, theoremthm}]
```

the log file contains

```
showing lemmathm
showing  propositionthm
showing  corollarythm
showing  theoremthm
```

and the additional space is considered as part of the theorem name to add.

With

```
\listoftheorems[ignoreall, show={lemmathm,propositionthm,corollarythm,theoremthm}]
```

the log file has

```
showing lemmathm
showing propositionthm
showing corollarythm
showing theoremthm
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much! "By the way, you should use `\cleardoublepage` before the `\addcontentsline` instructions." Why? "Of course you should also act on the space reserved for the numbers, but this is another matter." Yeah, that's a given. The styling options are limited, but I think it can be done. ; )

Comment: @FK82 `\listoftheorems` issues `\cleardoublepage`, so typically `\addcontentsline` will write out a different page number.